# Syntax for PALIVE in Python like pnbd.PAlive in R?

Tags: python, lifetimes-python

Can anyone help me to calculate PALIVE(the probability that they are still alive at the end of the calibration period.) in Python?

I know R has a Pareto negative binomial distribution [function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/BTYD/versions/2.4/topics/pnbd.PAlive) `pnbd.PAlive(params, r, s, apha, beta)`
but what is similar to it in Python?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `conditional_probability_alive` method from [`lifetimes`](https://github.com/CamDavidsonPilon/lifetimes) package. You need to pass `frequency`, `recency`, and `T` for each customer. For example for BetaGeoFitter (BG/NBD model):

```
from lifetimes import BetaGeoFitter
from lifetimes.datasets import load_cdnow_summary

# load data
data = load_cdnow_summary(index_col=[0])
print(data.head())

# fit lifetimes model
bgf = BetaGeoFitter(penalizer_coef=0.0)
bgf.fit(data['frequency'], data['recency'], data['T'])
print(bgf)

# predict p_alives for customers
p_alive1 = bgf.conditional_probability_alive(2, 30.43, 38.86)
p_alive2 = bgf.conditional_probability_alive(1, 30, 30)
print(p_alive1, p_alive2)
```

Output:

```
    frequency  recency      T
ID                           
1           2    30.43  38.86
2           1     1.71  38.86
3           0     0.00  38.86
4           0     0.00  38.86
5           0     0.00  38.86
<lifetimes.BetaGeoFitter: fitted with 2357 subjects, a: 0.79, alpha: 4.41, b: 2.43, r: 0.24>
0.7266084620654866 0.753658243186767
```

Comment: for the lot of times when my 4 value is high it gives me Nan for Palive.